# Conditional displaying of division REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The object "nextnode" is created everytime I dynamically create a node. I want to determine the value for the display of each division depending on whether the property "form" is set to null or not.

```
  const nextNode = {
        id: `node-${schema.nodes.length + 1}`,
        content: `Node ${schema.nodes.length + 1}`,
        coordinates: [
          desiredcoordinates[0],
          desiredcoordinates[1],
        ],
        parent: null,
        level: 2,
        form: null,
        className:'button blue',
        render: ({id,form}) => (
          <div id={id} style={{ fontSize: '0.5rem', textAlign: 'left', padding: '4px', width: '70px', height: '40px' }} onClick={() => toggleSelect(id)}>
            <a>
              <div style={{ display: ()=>form? 'block' : 'none' }}>
                <label>Form: </label><input style={{ width: '25px', height: '12px' }} type='text'></input>
                <button></button>
              </div>
              <div style={{ display: ()=>form?'none' : 'block' }}> Form: {form}</div>
              <div>

                <label>Func: </label><input style={{ width: '25px', height: '12px' }} type='text'></input>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        )
```

Comment: style={{ display: !!form? 'block' : 'none' }}

Answer (score 0):

It might not be what you are looking for, but have you considered not having the element in the dom when form is null?
It's called Conditional Rendering.

```
...
    {
    form &&  (<div style='display: block' > Form: {form}</div>)
    }
...
```

based on this:
https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator

If you want to use display then:

```
<div style={{ display: form ? 'none' : 'block' }}> Form: {form}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Condtional rendering

```
{form && (<div> Form: {form}</div>)}
```